# Oauth2 valid token JWT Spring

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt

What is the best way to check if token is valid for JWT token in oauth2.

Should I use this endpoint?

```
/oauth/check_token
```

I am not sure how to use it, and what it's doing.

The reason why i need validate token is that, I want to have some filter which will get me logged User, when correct token provided.

Or maybe I just should get userName from JWT Token and then ask database for User?

Comment: `Firebase Authentication` can take care of that for you: generating the token, verifying that it's valid, and having a list of users that logged into your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to validate an OAuth2 `JWT`. Basically it is always the same process: The `JWT` is signed by the issuer and the signature later gets validated from/for the recipient (you in your case). The `JWT` can be signed asymmetrical (with a private key from the issuer and a suitable certificate for validation) or symmetrical (same key for signing and validation).

---

**Validation on your own**

One way is to validate the `JWT` on your own (in your applications code), but for that you need to possess the key or public certificate. You can do this with the help of specific libraries (see [here](https://jwt.io/)).

**Validation by trusted third party**

Another way is to let the `JWT` be validated for you by a trusted third party. This can be done with the help of specific endpoints, like your suggested `/oauth/check_token` (see [here](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/endpoints/accessTokenValidation.html)). The endpoints url can vary for different identity provider. The advantage of this solution is that you do not have to implement the validation logic in your applications code and that you do not have to possess the key/certificate for validation. One big disadvantage is clearly, that you have one additional call for each `JWT` validation.

Comment: Additionally to your answer. I found out that we can make use of tokenStore.
tokenStore.readAuthentication(token) - gives us authenticated User.